# Recover files from corrupt DVD

Tags: linux, data-recovery, dvd

I have a DVD+RW containing a lot of images and videos. Multiple DVD drives fail to read or mount it. I tried to follow [this](http://riplinton.blogspot.com/2008/04/using-gnulinux-tools-to-recover-dvd.html) to try and recover the files using DVDisaster, and have created an iso file. But after that, I am lost. The instructions apply to a video DVD, not a data one, so the "split" command doesn't make sense. The iso file created by DVDisaster can't be mounted either in linux (with the "mount" command) or Windows (I understand it creates something like a "raw" image, though I'm not sure of the technicalities). Any idea what to do now? The error I get with mount is:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: What does `file /path/to/image_file.iso` show?

Comment: It shows "data".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try using PhotoRec with your corrupt image file. It can recover a lot of file types, not just photos as the name may imply.

I have used PhotoRec successfully even when I could no longer list the partitions from an image of a broken HDD.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: PhotoRec was just what the doctor ordered. Thanks a bunch, Inutil.

Answer (score 2):

Since `file` doesn't recognize your image as a known format, key parts of the filesystem are damaged, so you won't be able to mount it. To recover individual files that aren't too damaged, use [carving tools](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools%3aData_Recovery#Carving) such as [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/), [MagicRescue](http://www.itu.dk/people/jobr/magicrescue/), [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (from the makers of [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)), [RecoverJPEG](http://www.rfc1149.net/devel/recoverjpeg.html), … Most of these tools are available on typical unix distributions. But if you prefer, you can run a [special-purpose distribution](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) or other live CD including recovery tools such as [SysRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page), [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html), [CAINE](http://www.caine-live.net/)…

Answer (score 1):

If the image is valid (which will probably depend on how much data you managed to recover) then you should be able to loopback mount it on linux like this:

```
mount -o loop /path/to/image.iso /path/to/mount/point
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @user3671: In what way does it not work? Error? You can't get into the mount?

Comment: Nope, it won't mount. The "Note Added 04/12/2008" posting in the original link might be a clue: "I keep getting suggestions that all I need to do is mount the .iso or burn it to a new blank disk to get the video files. ... The .iso does not contain that data and will not mount even if you specify the type with the -t option to the mount command. Writing the .iso to a new blank will create another disk with the missing data."

Answer (score 1):

There is still a small possibility that your linux system does not have support for the UDF file system. To check that, you can try `zgrep UDF /proc/config.gz`. If `CONFIG_UDF_FS=y` (or `=m`) then it is not the source of your problems and most probably your iso image contains corrupted data.